# Choosing a CPU for gaming/development PC

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, cpu

I am going to be building a PC and i have chosen all components, but the CPU. I have stopped on i7-6700k and i7-6800k. I know that for gaming the i7-6700k will have better performance, but i am going to be using my PC for programming/developing applications on VM (Windows 10 with Visual Studio, Eclipse, etc.). So, is the i7-6700k with its 4 cores (2 on the Host and 2 on the Guest) the enough or the i7-6800k with its 6 cores (2 on the Host and 4 on the Guest or 3 on the Host and 3 on the Guest) the better choice? I am just not sure that the i7-6700k will provide me a smooth experience like i am not on a VM.

Comment: You are asking an off-topic question (hardware shopping). Please read [On-Topic](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic), [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://superuser.com/help/dont-ask). You could try [Hardware Recommendations](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @DavidPostill I disagree this being a hardware recommendation, given that he specifies 2 CPU's and wants to know why to choose one over the other. That boils down to why you want a 4 core CPU over a 6 core CPU. So it becomes a technical question if you remove the actual CPU's. That said, it is still primary opinion based though, and that IS offtopic on super user.

Comment: Do you know any game that currently requires more than  i7-6800k as  recommended hardware?

Comment: @LPChip <shrug> Either way it's off-topic. He's asking us to **recommend** a CPU (hardware).

Comment: OK, guys, i am sorry for the mistake. I will post in Hardware Recommendations, but how to delete my post?

Comment: @KrasimirKrustev - You can't.  You have recieved an answer that recieved an upvote.  Even if you could remove it, removing it after you recieve an answer, is in extremly poor taste.

Answer (score 1):

For a VM, the more cores you can assign to a Virtual Machine, the better its performance will be. The question is going to be, what will you do in the VM, and how many VM's do you plan on using?

I run a VM myself on a much lower processor. It has 4 cores. I have selected 1 core for the host, 1 core for my domain controller, and 2 cores for my remote desktop server. The performance is exemplary, but I had to upgrade my memory from 8gb to 16gb, because the host needed some memory too. Now I have assigned 4-8gb mem for the host and the rest for my guests.

If you look at the price difference and you can afford the i7-6800k, go for that one. The difference in gaming is neglectable and likely compensated for a good GPU. The extra cores will definitely help you in the future if you plan on expanding your VM.

Comment: Please don't answer off-topic questions. Doing so just encourages more users to keep asking them.

Comment: At the time of writing, I did not consider this question off-topic. It was after I stated my answer that I considered it might be opinion based.